# “Je ne sais pu...” I don't understand the function of “pu” here

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation, registre-familier

I don't understand the meaning or the importance of “pu” in these sentences

> Je ne sais pu quoi faire
>
> je ne sais pu c'est de quel côté c'est ici ou ici

Not sure what grammar form this is either.

Comment: It's spoken language, it should be *plus*. It should not be written like that, if they wanted to reproduce spoken language then it should be something like *je n'sais pu* or *j'sais pu*.

Comment: @Laure, that can be "pushed" to "chai pu" ; )

Comment: It is spoken language. I should have mentioned it was subtitles. Not sure what the pu means in "je n'sais pu" either though, doesn't seem any different like that anyway, just that the ne is contracted.

Comment: As @Laure said, it is for "plus" in the sens of "no more" => "I no more know what to do". And can also mean something like "I have exhausted all what I can do, so now I know no more solution".

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. Actually I tell a lie, the first line was not in subtitles, I found it here in an attempt to understand what the phrase that I heard in the subtitles meant: http://forum.ados.fr/love/Amour/sais-sujet_76714_1.htm

Comment: In the linked text, she alternatively uses "plus" or "pu"... my guess is there is no particular will here to mean something special and she's just using what comes to her mind while writing.

Comment: Ok so its not a mistake at all in speech, its perfectly fine and can be exchanged for 'plus' with the same meaning. Ok I get it, thanks.

Comment: @Hasen, yes, but please consider that "pu" is not a correct word even if we can understand it: so you should not normally use it or if you do, be sure the context is appropriated for that. So for instance in a very informal conversation or in a forum, why not. But for a professional letter, don't use it.

Comment: Sorry to extend again here, but I need to be clearer: "pu" with this meaning IS a mistake even in speech.

Comment: I added a bit to my answer, to address your comment.

Answer (score 5):

**It is spoken language. I should have mentioned it was subtitles.**

Subtitles are often mis-spelled, or spell the word as it's pronounced or mis-heard (so if it's mis-pronounced it's mis-spelled, or if it's pronounced colloquially rather than formally).

**Je ne sais pu quoi faire**

It should be spelled, *Je ne sais plus quoi faire* i.e. "I no longer know what to do" or "I don't know what to do anymore".

**je ne sais pu c'est de quel côté c'est ici ou ici**

"I don't know any more -- which side is it -- is it [or 'it is'] here or here"

**Ok so its not a mistake at all in speech, its perfectly fine and can be exchanged for 'plus' with the same meaning. Ok I get it, thanks.**

There are several versions of French -- see [Registres de langue en français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais) for example -- and ideally you'll use the right one for the [social] context.

(Plus there's local *patois*).

People go to school to learn the *courant* and *soutenu* (correct and formal) versions: in which *pu* is *une faute*, and *plus* is correct.

A benefit of school French is that it's relatively clear and doesn't result in questions like this one ... it's also maybe the most "polite", and may be expected in a business context, etc.

I'm not sure what the benefit of informal French is -- perhaps it's to mark you as an insider of a social [in-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingroups_and_outgroups), friends who can take liberties (with the language) with each other.

Because I've been to school, when I listen to the radio I can understand every word they say on [France Culture](https://www.franceculture.fr/), for example ... and I understand almost nothing they say (e.g. I miss at least one word per sentence) on a youth-oriented music station when the DJs are chatting and joking with each other.

Comment: Why would it be written with incorrect grammar if it was mis-heard? The first line actually was not subtitles, I found it here in an attempt to understand what the phrase meant: http://forum.ados.fr/love/Amour/sais-sujet_76714_1.htm

Comment: Maybe it's an attempt to reproduce, in writing, the informal pronunciation of personal conversation -- as a style for online dialog ... like writing, "geez I dunno!" in English. The site you quoted is a forum for teenagers -- it doesn't surprise me that teenagers have their own dialect.